# Django south: Re-run first migration

Tags: django, django-models, django-south

I made a mistake in the model declaration of an app and now need to re-run the initial migration.

Is there another way than deleting tables of this app and the entry in the migration history of south?

My setup:

Django 1.3.1

South 0.7.3

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
./manage.py migrate myapp zero
```

[Docs](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/commands.html#migrate)

Comment: Note that if you have any data migrations these need to be specifically written to be reversible (pass two functions to RunPython, one for forward, one for backward).

Comment: Still works in Django 1.7+, docs here now: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#migrate